# Why is the pop up overlay considering the state to be null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a pop up with an overlay. I want to close the pop up when the overlay is clicked or the button that opened it is clicked on again.

I have created a state called `[popUpState, setPopUpState] = useState(null);` for the same.

I am **rendering this state** through my return. So it should not display initially as it is null and should display when the state is set to the React element of `<PopUp />`. Which works great with the button click but when the overlay is clicked on it goes into the if statement i.e. it considers the state to be null.

Why is the state null here and not the div element with the className of footerPopUpOverlay?

```
const [popUpState, setPopUpState] = useState(null);

  const openPopUp = () => {
    if (!popUpState) {
      setPopUpState(
        <div className="footerPopUpOverlay" onClick={openPopUp}>
          <div id='footerPopUp'>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      setPopUpState(null);
    }
  };

  return(
    <div id='footer'>
        <button id='Btn' onClick={openPopUp}>Button</button>
        {popUpState}
    </div>
  )
```

PS: I have created the above functionality that works as required using another method that is by inverting the state's value on click and displaying the popup only when the state is true(written below). **But I am trying to understand what is flow of the state in the above code(why is it null)**.

```
 const [popUpState, setPopUpState] = useState(false);

  return(
    <div id='footer'>
        <button id='Btn' onClick={() => setPopUpState(!popUpState)}>Button</button>
        {popUpState ? <div className="footerPopUpOverlay" onClick={() => setPopUpState(false)}>
          <div id='footerPopUp'>
          </div>
        </div> : null}
    </div>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your state is either null or JSX. When the popup is shown it means that your check `if (!popUpState)` will resolve to false, that's why it resolves the else

Have a look at the following example:
[React modal](https://codepen.io/AdamMorsi/pen/mgBdWy)

Comment: When the pop up has been opened the state is set as the jsx component. When trying to close this pop up, why is the openPopUp function considering the state as null?